# Data Connectors from Sheets to BigQuery table not importing

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a Sheet with data coming from a G-Form response. Using the Sheets' data connector I was able to make a connection to a BigQuery Table, but the Sheets data is not importing, and am unable to figure out why.

**Sheets Data from Forms**

```
TimeStamp           |  Email Address   | Check box if info provided
10/02/2021 10:28:32 | jondoe@gmail.com | Name, Address, City
10/02/2021 12:32:44 | jaxdoe@gmail.com | Name, Address, City, Zip
10/03/2021 01:22:11 | jandoe@gmail.com | Name
```

**BigQuery Table Fields and Schema**

```
Field name    | Type       | Mode
Timestamp     | DATETIME   | NULLABLE           
Email_Address | STRING(255)| NULLABLE           
Response      | STRING     | NULLABLE
```

**Data Preview after refreshing**
[image]

Comment: Hi @hSin, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to directly add data from sheets to BigQuery. For your requirement you can import the sheet to drive and export data to bigquery using `Add` data option in BigQuery.

You can connect Public Dataset tables and other tables in BigQuery to Sheets as you are doing following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets).